# Splitting datetime into date/year/month/dayname and count year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I got question to split date, month year, dayname from datetime by using trigger, when I insert a datetime, then in next column will split date, time, month year dayname and count year (to know how old the man in my data) is that possible ?

For example, if I insert

```
INSERT INTO MAN VALUES ('04/06/1982')
```

then will be like this

```
DATETIME                  DATE         MONTH     YEAR      DAYNAME     AGE
04/06/1982 00:00:00       04           06        1982      friday      27
```

Comment: Why are you not using ISO 8601? "19820406"

Comment: kk i got this, but thanks for rememberme about ambiguity

Comment: Question: why use triggers when you can use calculated columns? Takes less space, can be indexed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
Declare @myDate datetime 
set @myDate='19820604'    --YYYYMMDD


Select @myDate as DateTime,
       datename(day,@myDate) as Date,
       month(@myDate) as Month,
       datename(year,@myDate) as Year,
       Datename(weekday,@myDate) as DayName,
       DATEDIFF ( year , @myDate , getdate() ) as Age
```

Result

```
  ╔══════════════════════════════╦══════╦═══════╦══════╦═════════╦══════════╗
  ║           DateTime           ║ DATE ║ MONTH ║ YEAR ║ DAYNAME ║ Age      ║
  ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════╬═══════╬══════╬═════════╬══════════╣
  ║ April, 06 1982 00:00:00+0000 ║    4 ║     6 ║ 1982 ║ Friday  ║       31 ║
  ╚══════════════════════════════╩══════╩═══════╩══════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

SQL Fiddle [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13414)

Comment: It could be US though: we don't know. This is why we have ISO 8601 formats to remove this ambiguity

Comment: nope gbn, i got this. if month become month name, can ? ex, that month 6, the result will be june

Comment: @gbn yup ur right .But seeing his result ,it seesms he is using dmy format.Anyways updated my ans using ISO format

Answer (score 0):

The code has been slightky altered to give the age correctly.

```
    Select myDate,myDateDate,myDateMonth,myDateYear,myDateDayName, Convert(varchar(50),Age)+ ' Years and '+Convert(varchar(50),nodays) +'days' {Age] from
        (
        Select @myDate as myDate,
               datename(day,@myDate) as myDateDate,
               month(@myDate) as myDateMonth,
               datename(year,@myDate) as myDateYear,
               Datename(weekday,@myDate) as myDateDayName,
               DATEDIFF ( year , @myDate , getdate() ) Age  , 
               DATEDIFF       ( dd , @myDate , getdate() ) -365* DATEDIFF ( year , @myDate , getdate() )   as nodays
        ) As a
```

Thanks
Arun

Comment: how to create trigger to split like this ?

Comment: You need to create an after insert trigger  on the column you insert the actual value, from inserted table you can also split and update in the next column

Answer (score 0):

Here there are two approaches for solving the issue:

**-** **Approach 1:**
you can add some computed columns in to your table, so when you retrieve the table contents the other remaining fields are computed in that time.

```
-- 1.1) Create the base of table 'MAN'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MAN](
    [DATETIME] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- 1.2) Insert a record in it
INSERT INTO MAN VALUES ('04/06/1982')
GO

-- 1.3) Add some computed columns
ALTER TABLE MAN
ADD
    [DAY]       AS DATENAME(DAY, [DATETIME]),
    [MONTH]     AS MONTH([DATETIME]),
    [YEAR]      AS DATENAME(YEAR, [DATETIME]),
    [DAYNAME]   AS DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [DATETIME]),
    [AGE]       AS DATEDIFF(YEAR, [DATETIME], GETDATE())
GO

-- 1.4) See the result
SELECT * FROM MAN
```

**-** **Approach 2:**
While you creating the table, you add the remaining fields that you need, so that in the next phase you add insert/update triggers in order to calculate the remaining fields and insert/update them.

```
-- 2.1) Create the table 'MAN' with all needed columns
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MAN](
    [DATETIME]  [datetime]      NOT NULL,
    [DAY]       [int]           NULL,
    [MONTH]     [int]           NULL,
    [YEAR]      [int]           NULL,
    [DAYNAME]   [nvarchar](10)  NULL,
    [AGE]       [int]           NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- 2.2) Create Insert and update triggers in order to calculate the values of the rest fields while inserting/updating
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trCalculateRemainingDateFields] ON MAN
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE  MAN
    SET
        [DAY]       = DATENAME(DAY, MAN.[DATETIME]),
        [MONTH]     = MONTH(MAN.[DATETIME]),
        [YEAR]      = DATENAME(YEAR, MAN.[DATETIME]),
        [DAYNAME]   = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, MAN.[DATETIME]),
        [AGE]       = DATEDIFF(YEAR, MAN.[DATETIME], GETDATE())

    FROM    Inserted i
    WHERE   i.[DATETIME] = MAN.[DATETIME]
END
GO


-- 2.3) Insert a record in it
INSERT INTO MAN ([DATETIME]) VALUES ('04/06/1985')
GO

-- 2.4) See the result
SELECT * FROM MAN
```

**-** **Approach 3:**
Creating a view of the main table which calculate the remaining fields can be a good option.

```
-- 3.1) Create the base of table 'MAN'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MAN](
    [DATETIME] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- 3.2) Insert a record in it
INSERT INTO MAN VALUES ('04/06/1982')
GO

-- 3.3) Create a view which is contained the remaining fields
CREATE VIEW dbo.vMAN
AS
    SELECT  [DATETIME],
            DATENAME(DAY, [DATETIME])               AS [DAY],
            MONTH([DATETIME])                       AS [MONTH],
            DATENAME(YEAR, [DATETIME])              AS [YEAR],
            DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [DATETIME])           AS [DAYNAME],
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, [DATETIME], GETDATE())   AS [AGE]    
    FROM    MAN
GO

-- 3.4) See the result
SELECT * FROM vMAN
```